# Is there a design pattern to manage parallel AJAX queries?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I am developing a web application retrieving data from several web services (let's say only two to simplify). What has to be retrieved from one service does not depend on what has been retrieved from the other, so I can launch AJAX requests in parallel. I need then to perform some actions once **both** queries have returned their data. Since it seems to be something very usual, I am wondering if there is a well-formalised and accepted design pattern to do that. What I am doing so far is there (using jquery):

```
var data1 = null;
var data2 = null;

$.ajax({
    url : url1,
    success: function(data) {
        data1 = data;
        if(data2) perform();
    },
});

$.ajax({
    url : url2,
    success: function(data) {
        data2 = data;
        if(data1) perform();
    },
});

function perform() {
    //do interesting stuff on data1 and data2
}
```

Would you do like that as-well ?

Comment: Async.js provides a nice library for handling groups of asynchronous methods.  In particular, you can use the async.each() method to run a set of them in parallel.

Comment: Async.js is perfect for my need. But since I am already using JQuery, the $.when().then(); is more adapted for my case - I guess. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like this

Check : jQuery: api.jquery.com/jquery.when

we can use jQuery's `$.when()` method, which takes a list of these "Deferred" objects (All jQuery Ajax methods return Deferred objects) and then provides a single callback.

Syntax

```
$.when(

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request)

).then(function() {

  // All have been resolved (or rejected), do your thing

});
```

Example :

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Comment: Is this based on the Q library?

Comment: @Crozin so yeah, it seems to be based on the q library then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is exactly the kind of trick I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When I have multiple ajax queries I usually like to keep a list of URLs. I create a list of promises and apply the `$.when` function to them. Something like this:

```
var urls = [url1, url2];

var endpoints = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=1) {
  endpoints.push($.ajax(urls[i]));
}
$.when.apply($, endpoints).done(function () {
  // Function arguments array differs if we have one or more than one endpoint.
  // When called with one endpoint arguments is an array of three elements [data, textStatus, jqXHR].
  // When called with more than one endpoint arguments is an array of arrays [[data, textStatus, jqXHR], ...].
  // Normalize the single endpoint to the generic list one.
  var args = endpoints.length > 1 ? arguments : [arguments];
});
```

Or more concise:

```
var urls = ['page1', 'page2'];
$.when.apply($, $.map(urls, $.ajax)).done(function () {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will use that for long lists of queries.